# Ext TreeStore Not Load

Tags: json, extjs

i used NestedList with TreeStore in sencha. 
My model,store and list here:

```
Ext.define('ListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'pid' },
            { name: 'name' },
            { name: 'GroupVariations' }]
    }
});

var treeS=Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
   model: "ListItem",
    config:{
         storeId:'treeS',
         autoLoad: true,
         defaultRootProperty: "Items",
          proxy: {
            type: "jsonP",
            url: "myjosn/data.json",
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                root: 'Items'
            }
        },
    root:{
        text:"Items",
        expanded: true
    }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {
    fullscreen: true,
    store: treeS,
    title: 'Varyasyonlar',
     displayField: 'name'
});
```

My json data:

```
[
  {
    "pid": 117,
    "name": "beklet",
    "Items": []
  },
  {
    "pid": -1,
    "name": "PASTALAR",
    "Items": [
      {
        "pid": 152,
        "name": "ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 153,
        "name": "MUZLU PASTA",
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 154,
        "name": "ÇİLEKLİ PASTA",
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 155,
        "name": "BEYAZ ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
        "Items": []
      }
    ]`enter code here`
  }
]
```

I'm installing as local data this json and It's work. But It's not work with url.Because store not filled.

```
console.log(treeS) => Output => f,item,data,items: Array[0]
```

Why does not work?

```
I tried, my json this format:
```

[{"Items":[{"pid":117,"name":"beklet","Items":[]}]},{"Items":[{"pid":-1,"name":"PASTALAR","Items":[{"pid":152,"name":"ÇİKOLATALI PASTA","Items":[]},{"pid":153,"name":"MUZLU PASTA","Items":[]},{"pid":154,"name":"ÇİLEKLİ PASTA","Items":[]},{"pid":155,"name":"BEYAZ ÇİKOLATALI PASTA","Items":[]}]}]}]

But not work

Answer (score 0):

Add `Items`, which is defined as `root`, in the first level as follows:

Edit: Instead of sending JSON array, send as a JSON Object by changing first square brackets to curly brackets.

```
{"Items":[
  {
    "pid": 117,
    "name": "beklet",
    "Items": []
  },
  {
    "pid": -1,
    "name": "PASTALAR",
    "Items": [
      {
        "pid": 152,
        "name": "ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 153,
        "name": "MUZLU PASTA",
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 154,
        "name": "ÇİLEKLİ PASTA",
        "Items": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 155,
        "name": "BEYAZ ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
        "Items": []
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following json, The above json does not follow the tree structure.

```
[
{
    "pid": 117,
    "name": "beklet",
    "leaf": true
},
{
    "pid": -1,
    "name": "PASTALAR",
    "leaf": false,
    "Items": [
        {
            "pid": 152,
            "name": "ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "pid": 153,
            "name": "MUZLU PASTA",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "pid": 154,
            "name": "ÇİLEKLİ PASTA",
            "leaf": true
        },
        {
            "pid": 155,
            "name": "BEYAZ ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
            "leaf": true
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data should be like this

```
{"Children":[
  {
    "pid": 117,
    "name": "beklet",
    "leaf":false,
    "Children": []
  },
  {
    "pid": -1,
    "name": "PASTALAR",
    "leaf":false,
    "Children": [
      {
        "pid": 152,
        "name": "ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
        "leaf":false,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 153,
        "name": "MUZLU PASTA",
        "leaf":false,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 154,
        "name": "ÇİLEKLİ PASTA",
        "leaf":false,
        "Children": []
      },
      {
        "pid": 155,
        "name": "BEYAZ ÇİKOLATALI PASTA",
        "leaf":false,
        "Children": []
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

And reader should be like this

```
reader: {
    type: "json",
    root: 'Children'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Friends
I found then answer.
My json data model is:

```
Ext.define('Modifiers', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            name: 'price'
        },
        {
            name: 'selected'
        },
        {
            name: 'pid'
        },
        {
            name: 'must'
        },
        {
            name: 'mustGroup'
        },
        {
            name: 'isMultiSelect',
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        {
            name: 'Items'
        },
        {
            name:'isProductGroup'
        },
        {
            name:'isMultiSelect'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

The error here "id".
I changed "id" property in json data and Its work!!!
Good days friends...